# The perfect number after 28

Tags: c, loops, perfect-numbers

I've written a simple program to find the perfect number that is immediately after 28 (which is 496), however it is not working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num=29, sum=0, aux=1;

    while(aux!=0){
        for(int i=1; i<num; i++){
            if(!(num%i)){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }

        if(sum == num){
            printf("%d", sum);
            aux=0;
        }else{
            num++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not using a debugger was your first mistake.

Comment: Rather than `for(int i=1; i<num; i++){`. code will run much faster with `for(int i=1; i<=num/i; i++){`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize `sum` before each check.

```
    while(aux!=0){
        sum = 0; /* add this */
        for(int i=1; i<num; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have initialized the value of sum inside the while loop because it's value is not getting  reset to 0 after a number check and it keeps on increasing the later value , so finally it would be resulting in a error .